# Configure vim-diff to show different colors when using it for svn-diff

Tags: svn, vim, vimdiff

I have set up 'vimdiff' as my default svn-diff tool by adding below line to `~/.subversion/config`

```
diff-cmd = /home/ravikirn/svndiff/diffwrap.sh
```

> diffwrap.sh

```
!/bin/sh

# Configure your favorite diff program here.
DIFF="/usr/local/bin/vimdiff"

# Subversion provides the paths we need as the sixth and seventh
# parameters.
LEFT=${6}
RIGHT=${7}

# Call the diff command (change the following line to make sense for 
# your merge program).

$DIFF $LEFT $RIGHT
```

But, vimdiff puts all ugly colors to display the diff. I have black background and green font color, how can I modify vimdiff to show custom colors for this diff ? I want a more pleasant experience with the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define colors in your colorscheme file. There are a couple of group highlights for vimdiff:

```
DiffAdd     diff mode: Added line
DiffChange  diff mode: Changed line
DiffDelete  diff mode: Deleted line
DiffText    diff mode: Changed text within a changed line
```

Before you edit your colorscheme file, you can start experiment, by defining colors in a vim session, by doing like :

```
:highlight DiffDelete ctermfg=black ctermbg=yellow
```

After you found your colors, place them in your colroscheme, and be happy. Or just place your highlight declarations inside "vimrc". Depends what you prefer.

Btw, you also can switch your colorscheme when doing diff. For example if you prefer different color when diffing. This is done by this :

```
if &diff
    colorscheme some_other_scheme
endif
```

Good luck with experiments

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for ! I will experiment on this over the weekend.

Comment: link broken, spam ahead!