# How to change the background color of diffs in Vim?

Tags: vim, colors, diff, vimdiff

My current background color does not show some diffs properly

[image: appearance]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4757916/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvimdiff%5D+colors

Comment: If you want to see what color schemes are available, type `:colorscheme <tab>` and vim will show you a list. I often settle for `:colorscheme delek` for vimdiffs. I really should set it so in my `.vimrc` instead of manually changing it every time...

Answer (score 2):

If use `vimdiff` from command-line, modify your `.vimrc` in your `~/.vimrc` path.

```
if &diff
    colorscheme some_other_scheme
endif
```

[image]